# Prove that if $R$ is a principal ideal domain, then either $R \cong S$, or $S$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ and $S$ be integral domain and suppose that $\phi: R \rightarrow S$ is a surjective ring homomorphism. Prove that if $R$ is a principal ideal domain, then either $R \cong S$, or $S$ is a field.

This is what I know: S is a field so the only ideals of S is $\{0\}$ or S. $R$ is principal so all ideals of $R$ can be expressed as $(a)$ for some $a \in R$. Since $ker(R)$ is an ideal of $R$, $ker(R) = (b)$ for some $b \in R$. However, I don't understand how to use all these information at all. I am clueless on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The homomorphism theorem tells you that $S\cong R/\ker\phi$. Since $S$ is a domain we know that $\ker\phi$ is a prime ideal.

Now use the fact that a nonzero prime ideal in a principal ideal domain is maximal.

So, if $\ker\phi=(0)$, we have $R\cong S$. Otherwise…